# Bash variable number in ascending order

Tags: bash

I have a variable named "event_id" that represents an event number.
I want to run the script with a change of this variable from number 1 to number 65000.
This means that the script will run in cycles and each time the variable "event_id" will increase the number by 1 until it reaches 65000.

```
event_id="1"
curl -k -u api:1234 https://localhost 'search=index=test eventid='$event_id''
```

Please your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a loop

```
for ((i = 1 ; i < 65001 ; i++)); do
    curl -k -u api:1234 https://localhost "search=index=test eventid='${i}'"
done
```

Comment: I suggest to use `for ((i = 1 ; i <= 65000 ; i++))`.

Comment: also `; do` is necessary.

Comment: I get some error:  ./script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `curl'

Comment: Sorry, yes, missed the "; do" becuase I was focusing on the loop :) Probably want to start from 1 too, but tweak the numbers as needed. Honestly, this is a google question, not a SO question anyway ...